# Undefined variable error but what i want is working fine

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting Undefined variable error except that everything is working fine.
What i was trying to make is the output of top 10 race winners, it works with this code but showing Undefined variable for $ID
Here is the code

```
<?php
$query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `RaceWon` FROM `pdata` WHERE `banned`=0 ORDER BY `RaceWon` DESC LIMIT 10");
$query->execute();
if($query->rowCount() == 0)
{
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
}
while($data = $query->fetch())
{
    $ID++; //<- Undefined variable but the function works what i wanted
    echo "<tr><td>".$ID."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['RaceWon']."</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: you did not define `$ID` before usage, define  it above `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `RaceWon` FROM `pdata` WHERE `banned`=0 ORDER BY `RaceWon` DESC LIMIT 10");
$query->execute();
if($query->rowCount() == 0)
{
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
}
$ID = 0;
while($data = $query->fetch())
{
    $ID++; //<- Undefined variable but the function works what i wanted
    echo "<tr><td>".$ID."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['RaceWon']."</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to initialize `$ID` before the loop.

```
$ID = 0;
while ($data = $query->fetch())
{
    $ID++;
    ...
}
```

It works anyway because when you try to use an unitialized variable as a number, it's automatically converted to `0`. But it still prints the warning because it was initially undefined.